# Won't print calculations for hours and minutes to seconds

Tags: printing

I'm making a program that calculates minutes and hours into seconds but it won't print, would appreciate any help

```
enter_hours = int(input("Please enter number of hours: "))
enter_minutes = int(input("Please enter number of minutes: "))

def CalculateSeconds():
    hours = enter_hours * 3600
    minutes = enter_minutes * 60
    return(hours, minutes)
```

Comment: While you've returned the values,  you haven't used ```print``` to print the results.  Or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
def CalculateSeconds(enter_hours, enter_minutes):
    hours = enter_hours * 3600
    minutes = enter_minutes * 60
    return(hours, minutes)

seconds = CalculateSeconds(enter_hours=int(input("Enter first number: ")), 
                          enter_minutes=int(input("Enter second number: "))) 
print(seconds)
```